# How to numerically solve this partial differential equation and plot the output?

Tags: differential-equations, graphics, numerical-integration, visualization, version-7

Using *Mathematica*, I would like to numerically solve the following partial derivatives equation :
$$\tag{1}
\frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial T^2} -  \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial X^2}-  \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial Y^2}- \frac{\partial^2 \Phi}{\partial Z^2} + 2(\Phi^2 - 1) \, \Phi = 0,
$$
where $\Phi(T, X, Y, Z)$ is a real scalar function.  The initial conditions of the scalar field are defined as the following:
\begin{align}
\Phi(0, X, Y, Z) &= \mathfrak{F}(X, Y, Z), \tag{2} \\[2ex]
\frac{\partial \Phi}{\partial T} \, \Big|_{T = 0} &= \mathfrak{G}(X, Y, Z), \tag{3}
\end{align}
where $\mathfrak{F}(X, Y, Z)$ (field values at time $T = 0$) **and** $\mathfrak{G}(X, Y, Z)$ (field "velocity" at time $T = 0$) are arbitrary functions (I may even use **RandomReal**, but I'm still not sure this is appropriate since the field is supposed to be smooth and differentiable everywhere).

To simplify things, I dropped the $Z$ dependance, so everything are now defined on a 2D cartesian plane only, instead of 3D space.  I've also dropped the non-linear part of (1), so this becomes a simple waves equation.  Here's an almost working code, but it has several issues that I don't know how to fix:

```
    Tmax = 10;

WaveEquation = D[Phi[t, x, y], t, t] - D[Phi[t, x, y], x, x] - D[Phi[t, x, y], y, y] == 0;

BoundaryConditions = {
   Phi[t, 0, y] == 0,
   Phi[t, 2Pi, y] == 0,
   Phi[t, x, 0] == 0,
   Phi[t, x, 2Pi] == 0
   };

InitialConditions = {
   Phi[0, x, y] == 2Sin[x]^2 Sin[y],
   (D[Phi[t, x, y], t]/.t -> 0) == 0
   };

WaveSolution = NDSolve[
   Flatten@{WaveEquation, InitialConditions, BoundaryConditions},
    Phi,
   {t, 0, Tmax},
   {x, 0, 2Pi},
   {y, 0, 2Pi}
   ];

Manipulate[
 If[Temps < 0 || Temps > Tmax || Not[NumericQ[Temps]], Temps = 0];
 Plot3D[
  Evaluate[Phi[t, x, y]/.WaveSolution/.t -> Temps],
  {x, 0, 2Pi},
  {y, 0, 2Pi},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2Pi}, {0, 2Pi}, {-3, 3}},
  AxesLabel -> {
    Style["X",  Bold, 14],
    Style["Y",  Bold, 14],
    Style["\[CapitalPhi](T, X, Y)",  Bold, 14]
    },
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", (* Makes manipulation slow *)
  ImageSize -> 700,
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow",
  Method -> {"RotationControl" -> "Globe"},
  SphericalRegion -> True
  ],
 {
  {Temps, 0, Style[Row[{t / T}], Italic, 12]}, 0, Tmax, 0.0005,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"},
  AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "Slider"}
  },
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom,
 FrameMargins -> None,
 FrameLabel ->  {None, None, 
   Style["Evolution of a scalar field", Bold, 14, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"]}
 ]
```

Preview of what this code is doing:
[image]

1. I may be getting some singularities, jumps or bad representation of the wave, which should remains finite at all time.
2. In place of the "Quality" PerformanceGoal, what should I use to get a smooth animation when using the slider, while still getting a smooth display of the wave?
3. Do I really need the boundary conditions to plot the wave evolution from its initial conditions?  How can I define **periodic boundary conditions**, in place of the fixed boundary?  This plot isn't about a fixed membrane on a rigid frame.  It's more about a free field propagating around in infinite space.

So what is wrong with the code above?  How can I improve its output and accuracy?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What limitation have you found in `NDSolve`? Also Include *specific examples* of your initial conditions.

Comment: Post the equation in Mathematica code is better than LaTeX.

Comment: @cvgmt, what do you mean?

Comment: I believe that this question should be closed, to be replaced with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/236126/optimal-resolution-of-a-wave-equation?noredirect=1#comment596302_236126, which I think is clearer.